# regex how to match a capture group more than once

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
\{(\w+)(?:\{(\w+))+\}+\}
```

I need it to match any of the following

```
{a{b}}

{a{b{c}}}

{a{b{c{d...}}}}
```

But by using the regex for example on the last one it only matches two groups: `a` and `c` it doesn't match the `b` and 'c', or any other words that might be in between.

How do I get the group to match each single one like:

```
group #1: a
group #2: b
group #3: c
group #4: d
group #4: etc...
```

or like

```
group #1: a
group #2: [b, c, d, etc...]
```

Also how do I make it so that you have the same amount of `{` on the left is there are `}` on the right, otherwise don't match?

Thanks for the help,

David

Comment: In .NET, you may do that with a single regex like [`^{(?:(?<c>[^{}]+)|(?<o>{)|(?<-o>)})*(?(o)(?!))}$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%7b%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cc%3e%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%29%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%7b%29%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%29%7d%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29%7d%24&i=%7ba%7bb%7bc%7bd%7d%7d%7d%7d). Group "c" capture collection contains all the values you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a million, could you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: For dialects supporting recursion the regex is [`{\w+(?:|(?R))}`](https://regex101.com/r/bxIbTu/1)

Comment: @David, So, you are coding in .NET? Mind that this solution will split the texts that are split with nested `{}`: `{a{b{c{d}eee}}}` will yield `c` and `eee` in separate captures. Is that OK?

Comment: @DmitryEgorov; The PCRE solution above does not check if the whole string matches the pattern, and it does not keep "repeated captures". The solution, if modified a bit, can be used with PyPi Python `regex` though.

Comment: @David, is it C#? Please let know if you expect strings in `{a{b{c{d}eee}}}` format, and if yes, what the expected behavior is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thank you for pointing me out. Since PCRE seems to miss the capability of checking balanced groups and capturing in one go, I presented an alternative approach in my answer. Briefly it is: check the balanced group pattern only once in a lookahead anchored to `^` and then just grab the groups with global `(\w+)`search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET, a regex can 1) check balanced groups and 2) stores a capture collection per each capturing group in a group stack.

With  the following regex, you may extract all the texts inside each `{...}` *only* if the whole string starting with `{` and ending with `}` contains a balanced amount of those open/close curly braces:

```
^{(?:(?<c>[^{}]+)|(?<o>){|(?<-o>)})*(?(o)(?!))}$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%7b%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cc%3e%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%29%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%7b%29%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%7d%29%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29%7d%24&i=%7ba%7bb%7bc%7bd%7d%7d%7d%7d).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `{` - an open brace
- `(?:` - start of a group of alternatives:

  - `(?<c>[^{}]+)` - 1+ chars other than `{` and `}` captured into "c" group
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<o>{)` -  `{` is matched and a value is pushed to the Group "o" stack
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<-o>})`  - a `}` is matched and a value is popped from Group "o" stack
- `)*` - end  of the alternation group, repeated 0+ times
- `(?(o)(?!))` - a conditional construct checking if Group "o" stack is empty
- `}` - a close `}`
- `$` - end of string.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/CXdg9q):

```
var pattern = "^{(?:(?<c>[^{}]+)|(?<o>{)|(?<-o>}))*(?(o)(?!))}$";
var result = Regex.Matches("{a{bb{ccc{dd}}}}", pattern)
          .Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups["c"].Captures)
          .ToList();
```

Output for `{a{bb{ccc{dd}}}}` is `[a, bb, ccc, dd]` while for `{{a{bb{ccc{dd}}}}` (a `{` is added at the beginning), results are empty.

Answer (score 3):

For regex flavours supporting recursion (PCRE, Ruby) you may employ the following generic pattern:

```
^({\w+(?1)?})$
```

It allows to check if the input [matches the defined pattern](https://regex101.com/r/yqmWgc/1) but does not capture desired groups. See *Matching Balanced Constructs* section in http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html for details.

In order to capture the groups we may convert the pattern checking regex into a positive lookahead which would be checked only once at the start of string (`(?:^(?=({\w+(?1)?})$)|\G(?!\A))`) and then just capture all "words" using global search:

```
(?:^(?=({\w+(?1)?})$)|\G(?!\A)){(\w+)
```

The `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. are now in the second capture groups.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/2wsR10/2. PHP demo: https://ideone.com/UKTfcm.

**Explanation:**

- `(?:` - start of alternation group

  - [first alternative]:

    - `^` - start of string
    - `(?=` - start of positive lookahead
    - `({\w+(?1)?})` - the generic pattern from above
    - `$` - enf of string
    - `)` - end of positive lookahead
  - `|` - or
  - [second alternative]:

    - `\G` - [end of previous match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html)
    - `(?!\A)` - ensure the previous `\G` does not match the start of the input if the first alternative failed
- `)` - end of alternation group
- `{` - opening brace literally
- `(\w+)` -  a "word" captured in the second group.

---

Ruby has different syntax for recursion and the regex would be:

```
(?:^(?=({\w+\g<1>?})$)|\G(?!\A)){(\w+)
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/jOJRhwJvR4

Comment: Your [`(?:^(?=({\w+(?1)?})$)|\G){(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fPHZ6C/1) still matches strings with unbalanced `{...}`. Besides, to make the regex compatible with both PCRE and Ruby's Onigmo, you can replace `(?1)` with [`\g<1>`](https://regex101.com/r/JHqazg/1).

Comment: @Wiktor, thank you for the review. Adding `(?!\A)` or `(?!^)` to `\G` should fix the issue. Updated the answer.